# What is the proper way to create an Angular Library with multiple components?

Tags: angular, npm, angular-components, angular-library, npm-package

I am refactoring the core components that make up a lookup page into an angular library. I would like to have multiple components in this angular library, i.e. LookupControls, PagingHeader, PagingFooter, etc. I want to be able to put `<lookup-controls></lookup-controls>`, `<paging-header></paging-header>`, and `<paging-footer></paging-footer>` in the HTML in an angular application project where this library is installed as an npm package and use the components individually.

What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: To reference code in your question, click the "{}" button in the editor or type the markdown yourself by surrounding your code with 3 backticks on each side.

Answer (score 3):

- First, create your library, ex :

ng generate library mylib

- Then, create a component into your lib, ex:

ng generate component lookup-controls --project mylib

And the magic works !

Angular will not ask you which type of style you want to use. You can specify it in the command, ex :

ng generate component lookup-controls **--style=scss** --project mylib

Hope it can help you or someone else :)

Comment: It'll bring me "Could not find an NgModule. Use the '--skip-import' option to skip importing in NgModule."

Answer (score 1):

The Angular docs have a [useful guide](https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries) on creating libraries with the [CLI](https://angular.io/cli).

I've used that guide to create a couple libraries recently, one of which features 3 components. I found that it is best to create the library in a separate directory from the application that currently contains the components your are refactoring out, since it avoids some issues with testing your library locally by using it in your app.

Comment: I shared my module code with a friend and he pointed out that I was using BrowserModule when I should be using CommonModule. It seems like there’s a lot of stuff that is necessary but not obvious in creating an angular library vs an angular application, stuff that is not really covered in the documentation on the angular site which I have been reading through to try and understand.

Comment: The angular library I created is in a different directory, yes. I also discovered that I should use ng new [LibraryProjectName] --create-application=false to create the project housing the library.

Comment: I can't speak to your Browser vs Common Module issue, but if you lean on the CLI to set up the library, there aren't too many gotchas. There are several good tutorials online that explain some of the picky parts like peer dependencies. Here's a good one https://willtaylor.blog/complete-guide-to-angular-libraries/

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use the Angular CLI to build an Angular library (or if you haven't the right CLI version which implements it) you can use the [`angular-library-starter`](https://github.com/robisim74/angular-library-starter) made by Roberto Simonetti. This starter allows you to create a library for Angular apps compatible with AoT compilation and Tree shaking like an official package. The project is based on the official Angular packages.

It's with this starter that I made my first library [`ngx-smart-modal`](https://github.com/biig-io/ngx-smart-modal) and other libraries. Easy to build, test and maintain.

This starter comes with an example lib you can use and play with to get familiar with it.